# Automatic hierarchy filtering across all Power BI visual objects

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I would like to implement a drill-down functionality across all visual elements, where selecting a specific group of data leads to a deeper exploration at the hierarchy level in all my visuals.

Thanks

I understand that enabling the detail mode in a visual object can achieve the desired outcome, but currently, this applies only to that specific visual. I aim to automate the process so that all visual objects sharing the same hierarchy levels automatically drill down, eliminating the need for individual adjustments